# What's the purpose of (fit=True) here?

Tags: python, qr-code

I'm trying to generate a .png containing a qrcode.

```
import qrcode 

qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, box_size=10, border=2)

student_id = input("Enter your ID: ")
qr.add_data(student_id)

qr.make(fit=True)
```

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is best answered by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) in pypi.

> The version parameter is an integer from 1 to 40 that controls the
> size of the QR Code (the smallest, version 1, is a 21x21 matrix). Set
> to None and use the fit parameter when making the code to determine
> this automatically.

The docs are pretty clear here, with `fit=True` you automatically detect the size of the QR code.